How to find nail and plastic size for bit drill
I got following screw and it’s wall anchor, I have randomly found a drill bit and made the hole is wall but that was layman guess.
How can I know which bit to use for wall anchor, and nail?


Usually by the size.

I never drill for a wall anchor.  I use a punch or screw driver just larger than the tip of the wall anchor. I push a hole in the drywall, ( sometimes a screwing motion)  Then tap in the plastic anchor so it is tight.  The screw in type of anchors make their own holes.  If you are anchoring into concrete or block, the anchor package tells what size masonry bit is needed.

That screw looks way too small (short) for the wall anchor you showed.

Pilot holes for screws is the minimum or slightly less diameter(shaft diameter without threads).
For nails about 1/2 to 3/4 nail diameter.
For anchors it should on the label on the box/bag they came in.  If no label/instructions, use a slightly smaller diameter than maximum shaft size.  You should need to push hard to get the anchor in fully.

I forgot to add picture, I updated my question and what is Pilot holes?

@localhost   Pilot holes are drilled to prevent wood spitting or to make screws go in easier or for anchors to fit in.  For your anchor shown, just between the minimum flat sections and the rounded sections.

Why pilot holes for nails?

@Huesmann   Usually for furniture and/or close to wood edges.  Wood does split when something is driven into it.  It is worst if close to edges/ends(toe nailing studs/joists).

@crip659 don't you just use a narrower nail then?  The fastening power of a nail comes from the friction between the nail and wood, and drilling a pilot hole reduces the clamping force.

@Huesmann   Split wood does not hold nails that well also.  With nails it depends a lot on what is needed.  Toe nailing studs to plates most people do not bother, since it is more to hold in place than to hold together.

@crip659 well for toe nailing the nail will do its job to keep the stud in place laterally—there's no chance of pullout.
